# Kubernetes: Update all pods in parallel

Tags: kubernetes

Is there any way to perform an update action on all pods simultaneously?

We have a process running in kubernetes as a stateful set where we want to update all the pods at the same time. We cannot seem to find a configuration for that. I am aware of `rollingUpdate`, which only updates one pod at a time.

This is what we have currently

```
  updateStrategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      partition: 2
    type: RollingUpdate
```

I also tried with `maxUnavailable`, but still did not work.
Is there any other hack to get this done?

Comment: take a look at the ramped slow rollout you can find further info here: https://spot.io/resources/kubernetes-autoscaling/5-kubernetes-deployment-strategies-roll-out-like-the-pros/

Answer (score 1):

There is no native alternative for updating all pods simultaneously when using Statefulsets.

The closest thing to it is to use the [Parallel Pod Management policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/#parallel-pod-management), but it only affects the behavior for scaling operations (including initial setup) and doesn't work for updates.

---

Although, the OpenKruise project has an extended component suite that enables [Advanced StatefulSet](https://openkruise.io/docs/next/user-manuals/advancedstatefulset/) to update workflow.

Here is a minimal working example that will **upgrade all pods at once**:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps.kruise.io/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: sample
spec:
  replicas: 5
  serviceName: fake-service
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sample
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sample
    spec:
      readinessGates:
      - conditionType: InPlaceUpdateReady
      containers:
      - name: main
        image: nginx:alpine
  podManagementPolicy: Parallel
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 100%
```

Note this will **certainly cause downtime**, but you can adjust to something like `maxUnavailable: 50%` to make it more resilient.